# Multiple classes with little difference

Tags: vb.net, interface, dry, base-class

I have a class that will be used often. It's methods will be the same except for two variables. Is there a better way to use these classes without repeating the implementation?

Example:

```
Public Function insert(Of T)(ByVal record As T) As IRecord Implements ITable.insert
        Dim myClass As IRecord = New MyChangingClass
        Dim text As String = "This will Change"

        ...

        Return myClass
End Function
```

Comment: I think a bit more detail is needed in this such as class structure and what is actually changing instead of saying `except for two variables`

Comment: It's a db function. The two variables being the stored procedure being called, and the object being populated.

Comment: Can't you put a constraint on the generic type eg T As ISomeType and pass the sp name as a string?

Comment: Could you provide and example?

Comment: Sure, but first - what determines the type of `myClass`? How does `record` relate to this process?